# Web API won't deserialize json post to EF type

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Yesterday I had a working Web API implementation.  I come in today and my post parameters no longer deserialize into my entity objects

Here is my api Controller code:

```
    public class DocBooksMDController : ApiController
    {

        private BoxEntities db = new BoxEntities();

        // POST api/DocBooksMD/ack
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Acknowledge")]
        public HttpResponseMessage MarkMessageAcknowledged(DocBooksMDMessage messageIn)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // retrieve docBooksMDMessage
                var query = from messages in db.DocBooksMDMessages
                            where messages.MessageControlID == messageIn.MessageControlID
                            select messages;
                DocBooksMDMessage messageOut = query.FirstOrDefault();
                if (messageOut == null)
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new ArgumentException("Invalid Message Control ID"));
                }

                // Set Acknowledgement and Feedback
                messageOut.DateAcknowledged = DateTime.Now;
                messageOut.DocBooksFeedback = messageIn.DocBooksFeedback;
                db.SaveChanges();

                // send response
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, messageOut);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }

        // POST api/DocBooksMD/read
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Read")]
        public HttpResponseMessage MarkMessageRead(DocBooksMDMessage messageIn)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // retrieve docBooksMDMessage
                var query = from messages in db.DocBooksMDMessages
                            where messages.MessageControlID == messageIn.MessageControlID
                            select messages;
                DocBooksMDMessage messageOut = query.FirstOrDefault();
                if (messageOut == null)
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new ArgumentException("Invalid Message Control ID"));
                }

                // Set Read and Feedback
                if (messageIn.DateRead == null) messageIn.DateRead = DateTime.Now;
                messageOut.DateRead = DateTime.Now;
                messageOut.DocBooksFeedback = messageIn.DocBooksFeedback;
                db.SaveChanges();

                // send response
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, messageOut);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my entity class:

```
public partial class DocBooksMDMessage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ExamSourceID { get; set; }
    public string PatientLastName { get; set; }
    public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string PatientMRN { get; set; }
    public string ExamAccession { get; set; }
    public string ExamCode { get; set; }
    public string ExamDescription { get; set; }
    public string ReferringProviderCode { get; set; }
    public string ReferringProviderNPI { get; set; }
    public string ReferringProviderLastName { get; set; }
    public string ReferringProviderFirstName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string MessageControlID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAcknowledged { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateRead { get; set; }
    public string DocBooksFeedback { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the json request that worked yesterday, but doesnt work today:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Host: tbd:8080
Content-Length: 127
{
  "MessageControlID":"65991775",
  "DateAcknowledged":"2013-07-09T16:09:13.1564342-05:00",
  "DocBooksFeedback":"Test Feedback"
}
```

I'm really at a loss as how to proceed.

This shows that that method is getting the expected request body:

```
string body = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: `Here's the json request that worked yesterday, but doesn't work today:` - so I guess all that's left now is to simply look at the commit history in your source control between yesterday and today to see who commited the non-working code. Then compare the changes and eventually fix or revert back to the working version of the code.

Comment: yep -- that would be the case.  except I finished right before going home and didn't check in.  Since it only exists on my laptop, no one else has messed with it.  I've burned the last 3 hours trying to figure out what has changed to no avail.  I even rebuilt the project from scratch to no avail.

Comment: I am really sorry to hear that. Usually when I have a working version of the code I commit it to ensure that I never lose it. It's probably something you should consider doing in the future to avoid those weird situations.

Comment: Thanks for the rather obvious advice. I get it: checking in your code --> good \\ not checking in your code --> bad.  Did you have anything to contribute on my question?  I was more looking for insight on troubleshooting WebApi deserialization than advice on coding practices.

Comment: I tried adding a test controller using the API controller with read\write actions, using Entity Framework.  The GET actions work fine but the PUT and POST actions where I pass a json serialized object back to the controller fail because the object parameter is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok -- it's official. I am a moron.  I left the content type off the request header when I was working in fiddler.  The deserialization is working fine now:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```